# Disable percent stacking on legendItemClick in percent stacked column highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a percent stacked column chart from highcharts. On legend item click, by default that series is supposed to hide. But along with hiding that series it also redraws the chart by taking another series to 100%, when ideally it should not affect the other series y value and redraw with its original y value and not 100%.
Here the demo link: http://jsfiddle.net/kanz3/

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        events: {
            legendItemClick: function(event) {
            var visibility = this.visible ? 'visible' : 'hidden';     
            //chart.series.stacking='normal'
            }
        },
        stacking: 'percent'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to re-calculate your series data to be percentages, and then plot them with stacking: stacked. A bit of a pain, but calculating the percentages for each pair shouldn't be too hard.

```
 plotOptions: {
        series: {
            events: {
                legendItemClick: function(event) {
                    //console.log(this);
                    var visibility = this.visible ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
                    //this.stacking= 'normal'
                    //chart.series.yaxis.max = 70;
                 // console.log(chart);
                    //chart.redraw = false;          
                 //chart.series.stacking='normal'
                   // chart.type='line'
                }
            },
            stacking: 'stacked'
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [50,50,50,50]        
    },
            {
        data: [50,50,50,50]        
    }]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2bWMC/

Comment: Yes thanks for the reply but that would restrict me from using the original figures elsewhere, say in tooltips

Comment: Point taken. if it's just the tooltips you are worried about, you can fix that by specifying extra information in your data points, and customising the tooltips. Otherwise, I can't see a way to do what you want in a percent stacking chart.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by translate functions and additional parameter which keep group / series positions. http://jsfiddle.net/kanz3/1/

```
 plotOptions: {
        series: {
            events: {
                legendItemClick: function (event) {

                    if(!this.options.hidden)
                    {
                        this.options.groupXY.x = this.group.translateX;
                        this.options.groupXY.y = this.group.translateX;
                        this.group.translate(1000,1000);
                        this.options.hidden = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.group.translate(this.options.groupXY.x, this.options.groupXY.y);
                         this.options.hidden = false;
                    }

                    return false;

                }
            },
            stacking: 'percent'
        }
    },

    series: [{
        groupXY: {
            hidden:false,
            x: 0,
            y: 0
        },
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }, {
        groupXY: {
            hidden:false,
            x: 0,
            y: 0
        },
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
```